# How to use IF statement for UILabel and String in Swift?

Tags: swift, string, if-statement, uilabel

For if timeInWord == "twelveAM" {

I got the following error: Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UILabel' and 'String'

Could you please fix this problem?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let scrollView = DScrollView()
    let scrollViewContainer = DScrollViewContainer(axis: .vertical, spacing: 10)
    let scrollViewElement = DScrollViewElement(height: 1200, backgroundColor: .lightGray)

    let timeComponents = ["twelveAM": "12 AM", "oneAM": "1 AM", "twoAM": "2 AM", "threeAM": "3 AM", "fourAM": "4 AM", "fiveAM": "5 AM", "sixAM": "6 AM", "sevenAM": "7 AM", "eightAM": "8 AM", "nineAM": "9 AM", "tenAM": "10 AM", "elevenAM": "11 AM", "Noon": "Noon", "onePM": "1 PM", "twoPM": "2 PM", "threePM": "3 PM", "fourPM": "4 PM", "fivePM": "5 PM", "sixPM": "6 PM", "sevenPM": "7 PM", "eightPM": "8 PM", "ninePM": "9 PM", "tenPM": "10 PM", "elevenPM": "11 PM", "midnight": "12 AM"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white


        view.addScrollView(scrollView, withSafeArea: .withSpaceForHeadline, hasStatusBarCover: false, statusBarBackgroundColor: .white, container: scrollViewContainer, elements: [scrollViewElement])


        for (timeInWord, timeInNumber) in timeComponents{
            let timeInWord = UILabel()
            timeInWord.text = timeInNumber
            scrollViewElement.addSubview(timeInWord)
            if timeInWord == "twelveAM" {
                timeInWord.edgeTo(scrollViewElement, safeArea: .twelveAm)
            }
            else {
                timeInWord.edgeTo(scrollViewElement, safeArea: .followingHour)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`timeInWord` is a `UILabel`.  `timeInWord.text` is a `String`.  So you should use `if timeInWord.text == "twelveAM"` if you want to compare the text in the label to some constant string.  You can get the type of any variable by option clicking it in Xcode.  Make sure the type is what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by:

```
for (timeInWord, timeInNumber) in timeComponents{
    let timeInWordLabel = UILabel()
    timeInWordLabel.text = timeInNumber
    scrollViewElement.addSubview(timeInWordLabel)
    if timeInWord == "twelveAM" {
        timeInWordLabel.edgeTo(scrollViewElement, safeArea: .twelveAm)
    }
    else {
        timeInWordLabel.edgeTo(scrollViewElement, safeArea: .followingHour)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As josh mentioned, you cannot compare UILable to string. You should check for UILablel's text. i.e UILabel.Text == "something"